# Selecting Data from Multiple rows and sorting it

Tags: php, sql

```
[   id    -   title   -   content  -   class]
[    1    -     t1    -     p1     -     1  ]
[    2    -     t2    -     p6     -     1  ]
[    3    -     t3    -     p5     -     2  ]
[    4    -     t4    -     p8     -     3  ]
```

For this table, How can i use 1 query to `SELECT` all classes `DISTINCTLY` to become this HTML

```
<label>Class: 1</label>
<div>t1, p1</div>
<div>t2, p6</div>

<label>Class: 2</label>
<div>t3, p5</div>

<label>Class: 3</label>
<div>t4, p8</div>
```

I really can't figure out a way to SELECT all the data and sort it at the same time at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to order by class and then title

```sql
SELECT title, content, class FROM your_table ORDER BY class, title
```

But the query isn't going to be able to produce that HTML. You'll need some logic in your PHP code to determine when the class changes.

```
$previous_class = null;  // $previous_class will store the class of the previous row. It's
                         // initialized to null because there's no previous row at first.

while ($row = some_fetch_function()) {

    // compare the current row's class to the previous row's class, and
    // output the class label if it has changed.
    if ($row['class'] !== $previous_class) {
        echo "<label>Class: $row[class]</label>";
    }
    $previous_class = $row['class'];
    echo "<div>$row[title], $row[content]</div>";
}
```

---

To answer your further questions about how it works, it's probably best to just step through the iterations of the loop.

First, you need to understand that the query results will already be sorted the way you need them to be, and the PHP is just providing a mechanism to output the class labels at the appropriate time. When you use the `ORDER BY class, title` clause in your query, the results will be sorted first by class, then by title for any rows that have the same class. So for your example, you'll get the rows in the same order you have them shown in your question.

So after `$previous_class` is initialized to `null`, this is what happens in the `while` loop:

1. First iteration: `$row = ['id' => 1, 'title' => 't1', 'content' => 'p1', 'class' => 1]`

   - `$row['class']` is `1`, and `$previous_class` is `null`, so the label is printed.
   - `$previous_class` is set to `1`.
   - `<div>t1, p1</div>` is printed
2. Second iteration: `$row = ['id' => 2, 'title' => 't2', 'content' => 'p6', 'class' => 1]`

   - `$row['class']` is `1`, and `$previous_class` is `1`, so the label is *not* printed.
   - `$previous_class` is set to `1` (again).
   - `<div>t2, p6</div>` is printed
3. Third iteration: `$row = ['id' => 3, 'title' => 't3', 'content' => 'p5', 'class' => 2]`

   - `$row['class']` is `2`, and `$previous_class` is `1`, so the label is printed.
   - `$previous_class` is set to `2`.
   - `<div>t3, p5</div>` is printed
4. Foruth iteration: `$row = ['id' => 4, 'title' => 't4', 'content' => 'p8', 'class' => 3]`

   - `$row['class']` is `3`, and `$previous_class` is `2`, so the label is printed.
   - `$previous_class` is set to `3`.
   - `<div>t4, p8</div>` is printed

Comment: can you please explain it more? I can't make it get into my mind.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious Before printing each row, you check whether the current class is the same as the class from the previous row. If it's not, you print the `<label>` for the new class.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious I'm not sure what else to add, but if you have more specific questions about how it works I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it works perfectly, The part of $prev_class = $row['class'], How does that sort it under each class exactly? I mean, Why doesn't it make a mistake like All classes under each other and then all titles and content under each other? How did that sort them correctly?

Comment: @Don'tPanic is it because when the prev_Class is null The query doesn't fetch?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious I updated the question with a more detailed description of what's going on in the loop. You should look into installing xdebug. If you use a debugger like that, you'll be able to step through your code like I've shown here, examine the values of the variables as it runs, and see for yourself what it's doing.

Comment: Sorry but there is a problem faced me in a new part using the same code, If i wanted to put all the <div>$row[title], $row[content]</div> inside a div, How can i do that? i'm tried putting it like this <label>Class: $row[class]</label><div> then <div>$row[title]</div> <div>$row[content]</div></div></div> but it is clearly illogical

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    title, content, class
FROM
    data
ORDER BY
    class, title
```