# Sort rows values depending on another row value without duplicating

Tags: php

From this table

```
[   id    -   title   -   content  -   class]
[    1    -     t1    -     p1     -     1  ]
[    2    -     t2    -     p6     -     1  ]
[    3    -     t3    -     p5     -     2  ]
[    4    -     t4    -     p8     -     3  ]
```

How can i SELECT each class distinctly and under of it the title and content in this HTML

```
<div>
  <div>Class: 1</div>
     <div>
        <div>t1, p1</div>
        <div>t2, p6</div>
     </div>
  <div>Class: 2</div>
     <div>
        <div>t3, p5</div>
     </div>
  <div>
  <div>Class: 3</div>
     <div>
        <div>t4, p8</div>
     </div>
  <div>
</div
```

Please use this to relate a hint about the modification of the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507106/7490349

Comment: output them in class order from the DB. Create a "Class: 1" div for the first class. Keep a record of the current class ID. Then loop through each row and output the title/contents divs. At each loop iteration, check whether the class ID has changed from the previous row. If it has, create a new "Class : x" div. That's really the simplest way.

Comment: @ADyson an example would be very useful at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your reference link and your output hope this help:

```
SELECT title, content, class FROM your_table ORDER BY class, title



$previous_class = null;  // $previous_class will store the class of the previous row. It's
                                     // initialized to null because there's no previous row at first.

    echo "<div>";
    $end_div = "";
    while ($row = some_fetch_function()) {

        // compare the current row's class to the previous row's class, and
        // output the class label if it has changed.

        if ($row['class'] !== $previous_class) {
            echo $end_div;
            echo "<div>Class: $row[class]</div>";
            echo "<div>";

        }
        $end_div = "</div>";
        $previous_class = $row['class'];
        echo "<div>$row[title], $row[content]</div>";

    }
    echo $end_div;
    echo "</div>";
```